# I want to find the Head of Abhishek using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to compare the value from the associative array and want to print the head of the person I have selected via the Html

My array looks like

```
var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.employee").change(function(){
        var selectedEmployee = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $.each( employee, function( key, value ) {
            if(employee["firstName"]==selectedEmployee) {
                $("div.print").html("The head of"+selectedEmployee+"is"+employee["Head"]["Name"]);
            }
        });
    });
});


<h3>1. Who is Head of </h3>
<select class="employee">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option name="Amith" id="Amith" value="Amith" >Amith</option>
    <option name="Sourasis" id="Sourasis" value="Sourasis">Sourasis</option>
    <option name="Abhisek" id="Abhishek" value="Abhisek">Abhisek</option>
    <option name="Sanjay" id="Sanjay" value="Sanjay">Sanjay</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You did not define `employee` and there is no `div.print` element.

Comment: there is a div element and i have gave it a class print

Comment: how to define employee ..Please help

Comment: I cannot define `employee` for you. You have written code to reference `employee`, so how come you don't have that variable? We cannot guess what data you are working with.

Comment: are you talking about employee array?

Comment: You should stop saying "please help". ;-)

Comment: See I have added the array named employee

Comment: (There is no need to add "please help" and other forms of pleading into every comment you make. While it may seem polite, it tends to grate on readers after a while, and it is probably best avoided. For more thoughts on this theme, [see this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions)).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for?

```js
var employee = [{
  "firstName": "Zahir",
  "lastName": "Alam",
  "Age": 25,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Department": "Tech",
  "Head": {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Sourasis Roy"
  }
}, {
  "firstName": "Amith",
  "lastName": "Manniken",
  "Age": 25,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Department": "Tech",
  "Head": {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Sourasis Roy"
  }
}, {
  "firstName": "Sourasis",
  "lastName": "Roy",
  "Age": 28,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "CTO"
}, {
  "firstName": "Aditya",
  "lastName": "Mishra",
  "Age": 29,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Department": "Tech",
  "Role": "CEO"
}, {
  "firstName": "Priti",
  "lastName": "Lata",
  "Age": 24,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HR"
}, {
  "firstName": "Sumita",
  "lastName": "Nath",
  "Age": 24,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HLA Head",
  "Department": "Crm"
}, {
  "firstName": "Tarini",
  "lastName": "Khanna",
  "Age": 22,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "Content Writer"
}, {
  "firstName": "Abhisek",
  "lastName": "Soni",
  "Age": 23,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HLA",
  "Department": "Crm",
  "Head": {
    "Id": 5,
    "Name": "Sumita Nath"
  }
}, {
  "firstName": "Ankit",
  "lastName": "Pump",
  "Age": 23,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HLA",
  "Department": "Crm",
  "Head": {
    "Id": 5,
    "Name": "Sumita Nath"
  }
}, {
  "firstName": "Pogo",
  "lastName": "Laal",
  "Age": 23,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "Designer"
}, {
  "firstName": "Sabina",
  "lastName": "Sekh",
  "Age": 28,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HLA Head",
  "Department": "Crm"
}, {
  "firstName": "Sanjay",
  "lastName": "Poudal",
  "Age": 24,
  "Company": "Switchme",
  "Role": "HLA Head",
  "Department": "Crm",
  "Head": {
    "Id": 10,
    "Name": "Sabina Sekh"
  }
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.employee").change(function() {
    var selectedEmployee = this.value
    $.each(employee, function(i, emp) {
      if (emp.firstName == selectedEmployee) {
        if (emp.Head) {
          $("div.print").html("The head of " + selectedEmployee + " is " + emp.Head.Name);
        } else {
          $("div.print").html(selectedEmployee + " has no head! ");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>1. Who is Head of </h3>
<select class="employee">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option name="Amith" id="Amith" value="Amith">Amith</option>
  <option name="Sourasis" id="Sourasis" value="Sourasis">Sourasis</option>
  <option name="Abhisek" id="Abhishek" value="Abhisek">Abhisek</option>
  <option name="Sanjay" id="Sanjay" value="Sanjay">Sanjay</option>
</select>

<hr>

<div class="print"></div>
```

Comment: No...See I have added an array

Comment: Ok, I've added the array to my example and updated it.  See if this works for you now

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- In your loop you should look at the properties of `value`, not of `employee`
- Add spacing to your output string or it will all cling together
- Some employee objects have no "Head" property, so you should deal with that case
- Once you have found the employee, you can exit the loop with `return false`.
- To get the selected value from the drop down, you don't really need to do `children("option:selected")`. You can do just `.val()` on the `select` jQuery element

You should do it like this:

```js
var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.employee").change(function(){
        var selectedEmployee = $(this).val();
        $.each( employee, function( key, value ) {
            if(value["firstName"] == selectedEmployee) {
                $("div.print").text("The head of " +selectedEmployee+" is "+ (value["Head"] ? value["Head"]["Name"] : "unknown"));
                return false; // exit;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>1. Who is Head of </h3>
<select class="employee">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option name="Amith" id="Amith" value="Amith" >Amith</option>
    <option name="Sourasis" id="Sourasis" value="Sourasis">Sourasis</option>
    <option name="Abhisek" id="Abhishek" value="Abhisek">Abhisek</option>
    <option name="Sanjay" id="Sanjay" value="Sanjay">Sanjay</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="print"></div>
```

Comment: did you refered my array?

Comment: Yes, I did..... See the working snippet in my answer. It has your array.